# Linkedin API - getting a Member_id from a URL

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to take a given URL (http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=6263712 or http://www.linkedin.com/in/rgrush/) that a user passes to my app and derive the app-specific 'member_id' of that person.  The info I'm trying to collect will be for 1st, 2nd, or 3rd connections of my app's OAuth user.

This method looked to be it `http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=<public-profile-url>` but all I'm seeing are the basic public profile fields, not the full info I'm able to get in the browser.

I've also seen some people suggest searching with criteria scraped from the page (name, company, location). It will give you the app-specific 'member_id' if you use something like this `http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search? keywords=[space delimited keywords]& first-name=[first name]& last-name=[last name]` but this seems messy and kind of defeats the purpose of going through the API.  Am I understanding everything correctly and is there a good solution for this?

Comment: Hello Ryan, did you find answer to this question?, because this is also my problem, please tell me if you solved this, thanks!

Comment: I don't think it was possible with the API if I recall correctly. Linkedin doesn't have a real common sense API IMO. Most of the info that is available to a user when navigating in their browser isn't available in the API.  This was a helpful place to test https://apigee.com/console/twitter, but even this is misleading ... They are/were using an older version of the API with more permissions. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

When you use r_fullprofile member permission, you get access to the full profile fields of ONLY the authenticated user. You can only retrieve the basic profile fields of the 1st degree connections of the authenticated user as explained in our Connections API doc. There are no member permissions that allow you to access the full profile fields of the connections. This restriction is added to protect the data privacy of our users.This issue is not with your code, you are getting what our Linkedin APIs allow.

Read the following link to understand more https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api